# Connecting a Kodak KAF-0402 (CCD-Sensor) to an ESP

Tags: esp8266, esp32, image-sensor

I have a Kodak [KAF-0402](https://tug.tubitak.gov.tr/sites/images/tug/kaf_402m.pdf) CCD sensor. I would like to connect it to an ESP8266 or ESP32.

After an intensive internet search I found nothing about this.
Can you confirm if this will work at all, and if so, which problems I can expect?

Answer (score 2):

This device might be tricky depending on your level of electronics and interfacing experience.  At base, you "just" have to to make the waveforms from the datasheet.  But they're moderately fast, you have to do the analogue-to-digital conversion, and some of the signals aren't that easy.

This Kodak device appears to be the same as the [Onsemi KAF-0402](https://www.onsemi.com/products/sensors/image-sensors/kaf-0402) which has a certain amount of technical documentation including a [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/kaf-0402-d.pdf) apparently identical in content to the Kodak one.  Onsemi say this device is end-of-life.

There is/was an evaluation kit KAF-0402-12-5-A-EVK whose datasheet shows this isn't a trivial device to interface to.  In particular you might note:

> **CCD Clock Drivers**
> Elantec clock drivers, designed to drive the large
> capacitance loads presented by the clock gates of the CCD,
> are used to generate the horizontal and vertical clocks.
> The Elantec drivers accept TTL inputs, and level shift to the
> required peak-to-peak voltage swing of the CCD clocks.
> The peak-to-peak swing of the clocks is adjustable.
> The outputs of the drivers are AC coupled, providing
> adjustable offset of the clocks from the negative rail to the
> positive rail. Using a separate IC for each vertical clock (V1,
> V2), a maximum 4 amp output drive current per vertical
> clock channel is available. A single IC is used to drive H1,
> and H2, giving a maximum 2 A output drive current per
> Horizontal clock channel.
> The reset clock driver utilizes two fast switching
> transistors, designed for a fast switching input signal with
> a narrow pulse width. The peak-to-peak voltage swing and
> the offset voltage are adjustable.
> **CCD Bias Voltages**
> CCD bias voltages (VRD, VOG, VLG) are supplied by
> filtered outputs of adjustable potentiometers. Fixed CCD
> bias voltages (LOD, VSS, GUARD) are supplied by filtered
> outputs of voltage dividers.
> -- [Onsemi KAF-0402-12-5-A-EVK datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/EVBUM2257_D-1273900.pdf)

My suggestion would be to start from the eval kit datasheet, which is designed to show how to use the CCD device.

Comment: Hi @jonathanjo, thank you very much for your answer. That helps me very much!